# Driver for 'dust removal' in Ubuntu 14.04 for lenovo ideapad z580

Tags: 14.04, lenovo, ubuntu-drivers

I bought a Lenovo Ideapad z580 laptop with preinstalled windows 8. After few months of use, I completely switched to Ubuntu. Everything is running fine, however I do miss the hot key for dust removal? Perhaps, the following picture in the [Image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pee72hg8goerfmf/20150131_100723.jpg?dl=0)  will help in understanding the question.

What do I need to do get it in work? I looked for drivers on Lenovo website but didn't find anything useful. Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Do you know what it does? im guessing it just revs the fan is that right? I bet you could make a python script to do it.  I would be inclined to search dmidecode, and dmesg for notes about the specific hardware, though off hand, Im not sure what you would be looking for. maybe search "LED" or "fan"

Comment: @j0h Actually, it controls the fan speed. Can you guide me a bit more on the python script. I know python programming but never used it with hardware stuff.

Comment: There are many fan control programs out there. to turn the LED on / off you need to know the address that controls it. https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/leds/leds-class.txt  worth reading. Then look for LED stuff in dmesg. sudo dmesg | grep "led device" so then you would make a file named brightness in /sys/class/leds/whateverDeviceName/ and then echo 1 > brightness to turn it on. Then turn it off with echo 0 > brightness. Im assuming you want to add LED function to whatever fan control program you choose.  once you figure out your hardware, youll write a trigger for LEDs from Fan Cntrl